# Expression<Action<T>> methodCall

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

How do I run methodCall inside Enqueue?

```
public static string Enqueue<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Action<T>> methodCall)
{
   // How to run methodCall with it's parameters? 
}
```

Calling method:

```
Enqueue<QueueController>(x => x.SomeMethod("param1", "param2"));
```

Comment: It is possible, but very expensive, because you must use reflection for this. Why don't you pass Action instead of Expression of Action?

Comment: @galenus: I am overloading a method in Hangfire.io, so I'm not in control of that part as the header have to match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to achieve that you will need an instance of `T` so that you can invoke the method on this instance. Also your `Enqueue` must return a string according to your signature. So:

```
public static string Enqueue<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, string>> methodCall)
    where T: new()
{
    T t = new T();
    Func<T, string> action = methodCall.Compile();
    return action(t);
}
```

As you can see I have added a generic constraint to the `T` parameter in order to be able to get an instance. If you are able to provide this instance from somewhere else then you could do so.

---

UPDATE:

As requested in the comments section here's how to use `Action<T>` instead:

```
public static string Enqueue<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Action<T>> methodCall)
    where T: new()
{
    T t = new T();
    Action<T> action = methodCall.Compile();
    action(t);

    return "WHATEVER";
}
```

Comment: Sorry I can't change the the way I call Enqueue as its an overload

Comment: OK, in this case simply use `Action<T>` instead. But it's up to you to return some string value from the `Enqueue` function. There's no way to get it from the execution of the `Action<T>` because `Action<T>` doesn't return anything.

Comment: I dont need to return anything. How do I extract and run Action<T> ? Thanks

Comment: Of course that you need to return something if the signature of your Enqueue method returns a string!!! Otherwise your code will not compile. I will update my answer to illustrate how to achieve that with an `Action<T>`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov This will not work, because there is no `where T: new()` constraint in the original signature and it was stated that the signature cannot be updated

Comment: Yes, that's why I explained in my answer that the OP will need to get an instance of `T` if he wants to be able to invoke the action. I have illustrated how he could use a `new()` constraint in order to automatically instantiate `T` inside the method but if he cannot change the signature it is more than obvious that he will need to provide this `T` instance from somewhere else.

Comment: I don't know how Hangfire.io gets the parameters extracted, but I was able to change it to an extension method rather than overload and then it worked like a charm. Thanks everyone for your help! The story behind is that Hangfire.io is a job scheduler but if the database behind fails then the job queueing fails. So I wanted to overload the method to run directly if the job failed.